# Add and Remove Event Listener - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am trying to add addEventListener when I click on a div. I already found many questions and answers but I didn't achieve to make it works.
Actually, I would like to pass some parameters to my eventListener.

At the beginning I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].addEventListener('click', customFunction(event, args1, args2));
```

But it was not working. Indeed, on a click it was not going into `customFunction`.

Therefore, I tried with `bind` :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].addEventListener('click', customFunction.bind(null, event, args1, args2));
```

This time, on a click it was passing into `customFunction`.

However, the param event is type Event and not MouseEvent. In the event object I don't have access to the currentTarget or things that I found usually in an event with addEventListener.

[image: screenshot event]

This is may due because here event is Event type whereas usually it is MouseEvent type.

I though to use anonymous function like this:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // do something
});
```

But I need to remove the eventListener and with anynomous function it is not cleaned to do so. It's better to store the object function in order to remove the addEventListener after that.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const clickEventListener = ['click', function (event) { 
      customFunction(event, args1, args2) 
    }];
    element.addEventListener(...clickEventListener);
    element.removeEventListener(...clickEventListener);
```

This fix my problem.

[medium link](https://medium.com/@agudulin/thanks-for-this-article-b46bb53054cd)

Answer (score 0):

Try by putting the `customFunction` inside the callback function like this

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  customFunction(event, args1, args2)
});
```

For removing event use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Yes, but how could I remove the addEventListener like this ? @brk

Comment: But in order to remove the EventListener it can not be anonymous function. And in the link you are showing it removes it with object function created before

Comment: remove listener from target element

Comment: What do you mean ? Imagine I have to different events listener on a div. How can I do to remove only one of them ? @brk

Answer (score 0):

You can JQuery to bind event

```js
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

REF : [JQuery Click Event](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Replace alert with your function

Comment: I would prefer to avoid to use JQuery... And by the way, how do you remove the event ?

Comment: user unbind() method. Ex **$("target").unbind();**

Comment: If I have to different events listener on the target. How can I do to remove only one of them ?